# Let $x\geq 1$, $n\in N$, show that $\prod_{i=1}^n(x+n-i)\geq x^{n+1} $

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

> Let $x\geq 1, n\in N$
>   Show that
>   $$
> \prod_{i=1}^n(x+n-i)\geq x^{n+1}
> $$

I can see that the product is greater or equal to $x^n$, but I cannot understand where power $n+1$ is coming from.

Comment: Doesn't the inequality fails for $n=1$? Are you sure the low index is $i=0$?

Comment: The LHS is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $x$, so this is **wrong** for any $n$ and sufficiently large $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you wanted to write $\prod_{i=0}^n(x+n-i)\geq x^{n+1}$, for all $x\geq 1$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Please note that your inequality fails if $n=1$.
If that's the case, you can use induction:

If $n=1$ then

$$\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=0}^n(x+n-i)&=\prod_{i=0}^1(x+1-i)\\
&=(x+1)x\\
&=x^2+x\\
&\geq x^2 \;\text{(because}\;x\geq 1 \text{)}
\end{align*}$$

Suppose now there's a $p\in \mathbb{N}$ so $\prod_{i=0}^p(x+p-i)\geq x^{p+1}$. So, if $n=p+1$, then

$$\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=0}^n(x+n-i)&=\prod_{i=0}^{p+1}[x+(p+1)-i]\\
&=x\prod_{i=0}^p[x+(p+1)-i]\\
&\geq x\prod_{i=0}^p(x+p-i) \;\text{(because}\;x+(p+1)-i\geq x+p-i \text{)}\\
&\geq xx^{p+1} \;\text{(because of the hypotheses)}\\
&=x^{(p+1)+1}\\
&=x^{n+1}\\
\end{align*}$$

So, $\;\prod_{i=0}^n(x+n-i)\geq x^{n+1}$, for all $x\geq 1$, $n\in \mathbb{N}\;\;\;\;QED$

Comment: This looks too complicated. Isn't it clear that $x+n-i \geq x$ for all $i$?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy, non the less is a valid method, right? But you're right. It is pretty clear that $x+n-i\geq x$.

Answer (score 1):

If the product starts with $i=0$ this is trivial. (If it starts with $i=1$ it is false). Just note that $x+n-i \geq x$ for each $i$ so the product is $\geq x^{n+1}$.